# jQuery to replace exact number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got a few divs with numbers from 0 to 3200 and want to replace them with a character.

example of html:

```
  <div>2</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>26</div>
```

example of jQuery:

```
   $('div').text(function () {
                return $(this).text().replace("1","K").replace("2","/").replace("3","@").replace("4","r").replace("5","[").replace("6","[").replace("7","[").replace("8",",").replace("9",",").replace("10","J").replace("11",",").replace("12",",").replace("13","P").replace("14","]").replace("15","]").replace("16","]").replace("17","R").replace("18","R").replace("19","N").replace("20","N").replace("21","N").replace("22","N").replace("23","W").replace("24","L").replace("25","d").replace("26","D").replace("27","(").replace("28","B").replace("29","b").replace("30","B").replace("31","a").replace("32","A").replace("33","f").replace("34","F").replace("35","[").replace("36",":").replace("37","@").replace("38","@").replace("39","!").replace("40","?").replace("41","Z").replace("42","]").replace("43","Z").replace("44","B").replace("45","@").replace("46","]").replace("47","@").replace("0","V").replace("3200","c");
            });
```

What I have got for 2 - / **correct**, for 6 - [ **correct**,  and for 26 - /[  **wrong** for 26 should be D.

Can you please help me with my jQuery code please? Live jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/UEy7w/

Comment: what u want can u explain it clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the approach:

```
var charMap = {
    '1' : 'K',
    '2' : '/',
    '3' : '@',
    '4' : 'r',
    '6' : '[',
    '26' : 'D'
    // please fill in the rest yourself
};

$('div').text(function (i,t) {
    return charMap[t] || t;
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XErt5/1/).

This approach avoids the `2` and `6` of `26` being assessed separately by passing the whole of the existing text `t` of the element as a key to the `charMap` object and returning the relevant character or, if one doesn't exist for that text, returning the old text itself.

References:

- 'Plain' JavaScript:

  - [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).
- jQuery:

  - [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: Hi David, your approach is amazing. Thank you.

Comment: You're very welcome; I'm glad to have been of help! :)

Answer (score 1):

You should replace 26 before you replace 2.. else the 2 of 26 will allready be replaced

Answer (score 0):

First, replace the longest numbers, like `26`. Then, replace `2`. That way, the `2` in `26` won't be replaced before you can "recognize" the `26`.

This should do the trick:

```
$('div').text(function () {
    return $(this).text()
        .replace("3200","c")
        .replace("10","J")
        .replace("11",",")
        .replace("12",",")
        .replace("13","P")
        .replace("14","]")
        .replace("15","]")
        .replace("16","]")
        .replace("17","R")
        .replace("18","R")
        .replace("19","N")
        .replace("20","N")
        .replace("21","N")
        .replace("22","N")
        .replace("23","W")
        .replace("24","L")
        .replace("25","d")
        .replace("26","D")
        .replace("27","(")
        .replace("28","B")
        .replace("29","b")
        .replace("30","B")
        .replace("31","a")
        .replace("32","A")
        .replace("33","f")
        .replace("34","F")
        .replace("35","[")
        .replace("36",":")
        .replace("37","@")
        .replace("38","@")
        .replace("39","!")
        .replace("40","?")
        .replace("41","Z")
        .replace("42","]")
        .replace("43","Z")
        .replace("44","B")
        .replace("45","@")
        .replace("46","]")
        .replace("47","@")
        .replace("0","V")
        .replace("1","K")
        .replace("2","/")
        .replace("3","@")
        .replace("4","r")
        .replace("5","[")
        .replace("6","[")
        .replace("7","[")
        .replace("8",",")
        .replace("9",",");
});
```

Comment: No problem, @qqruza. Please consider accepting this answer, but also have a look at what David Thomas posted, as it's a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

26 is getting replaced by 2 and 6 respectively. Place single digit replace code after two digit replace code.try this:

```
    $('div').text(function () {
                return $(this).text().replace("10","J").replace("11",",").replace("12",",").replace("13","P").replace("14","]").replace("15","]").replace("16","]").replace("17","R").replace("18","R").replace("19","N").replace("20","N").replace("21","N").replace("22","N").replace("23","W").replace("24","L").replace("25","d").replace("26","D").replace("27","(").replace("28","B").replace("29","b").replace("30","B").replace("31","a").replace("32","A").replace("33","f").replace("34","F").replace("35","[").replace("36",":").replace("37","@").replace("38","@").replace("39","!").replace("40","?").replace("41","Z").replace("42","]").replace("43","Z").replace("44","B").replace("45","@").replace("46","]").replace("47","@").replace("0","V").replace("3200","c").replace("1","K").replace("2","/").replace("3","@").replace("4","r").replace("5","[").replace("6","[").replace("7","[").replace("8",",").replace("9",",");
            });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UEy7w/2/)**

Comment: And now the single `2` isn't being replaced at all.
You just broke the replacement of the `2`.

Comment: Did not kept that in mind.Thanks cebrus updated now.

Comment: Now you're just doing exactly what I did, except you forgot about the `3200`.

Answer (score 0):

The replace function are executed in the order left to right. So, before your code for replacing a `26` gets called, the 2 and the 6 have already been replaced.

Solution: Reorder the calls to `.replace()`, ensuring that the none in the chain will break any future (= further to the right) replacement.

Better solution: Whatever you are doing, don't do it - it looks like it's built to fail.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are calling .replace() recursively on an already replaced text.

This is how your code works now.

```
"26".replace(2,'\')
"\6".replace((6,'[')
```

If you put your .replace('26',D) ahead of all other replace it will work as expected.

Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/bEqwP/1/

But this is not how you should proceed. I said this just to make you understand what is happening behind the scene. I would suggest the approach mentioned by David Thomas

Comment: I have done it in my jsFiddle but it doesn't seem working ;-(